# Is it possible to determine if you are placed perfectly stationary in outer space?

Tags: reference-frames, relativity, relative-motion

Many questions and answers that I read are saying that it's not possible to determine absolute stationary position in space. But when I think about it, it seems weird and unlikely.

If you cross-reference speed of multiple objects in space with each other and the speed of light (which is constant) you **should** be able to tell if you are perfectly stationary positioned in space without any movement.

Or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: You are going to be moving relative to something. Always.

Comment: There's no experiment you can do in your spaceship to distinguish between being stationary or moving with uniform speed. The laws of physics are the same for both situations. You may think you are stationary if you see other ships moving with respect to you, but any one of those ships sees you moving with respect to it.

Comment: There is a unique frame in which the cosmic microwave background temperature is isotropic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to determine whether you are in absolute stationary or not in outer space. Actually you cannot do that even on earth because absolute stationary does not exist. Remember that motion is absolute and stationary is relative. You can only tell whether you are stationary in a particular frame of reference. Moreover, if you can tell that you are stationary in a frame of reference, you still do not know whether the frame of reference is in motion or not because if the frame of reference is moving with constant velocity, you will never be able to know that it is in motion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute frame of reference. In any frame of reference the speed of light will always be the same, so you cannot use it to tell if you are moving or not. Even kinetic energy is frame dependent, and not invariant. Any frame of reference could correctly say that it is at rest, relative to other frames.